# Google results show weird naming for this site

Tags: bug

For some reason, when searching "reasons of hottest august this year earth science" in Google, it displays a weird title for this question:

> [image]

Note that it should be Earth Science Stack Exchange, and not EarthScience Stackexchange.

[bjb568 also repro'ed this](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2340984#2340984):

> [image]

[Some others in chat however couldn't reproduce this bug](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2340953#2340953):

> [image]

Is this something going wrong on the Stack Exchange side? Or is this Google's problem?

If it matters, I'm using Chrome 38.0.2125.8 dev-m.

Comment: [No-repro](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2340961#2340961) but +1 regardless.

Comment: [Repro'd in Firefox 31.](http://i.imgur.com/7bc5nb7.png).

Comment: Repro'd Chromium "Version 38.0.2125.0 (290040) (64-bit)" Linux

Comment: I can't reproduce this whether I use Maxthon or Safari...

Comment: Maybe it would help if you pasted the actual URL of the result page (may be due to one of the parameters).

Comment: @plannapus [URL I'm using](https://www.google.com/search?q=reasons+of+hottest+august+this+year+earth+science&oq=reasons+of+hottest+august+this+year+earth+science&aqs=chrome..69i57.465j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: Ah! Ok with your URL i can reproduce it on Maxthon, so it's not a browser thing it has to do with one of those parameters `&aqs=chrome..69i57.465j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8`

Comment: linux/firefox/google.com.au, I get **"meteorology - July/August hottest months (northern ..."** as the title (yes, with the ellipses). Using hichris123's URL, I get **"July/August hottest months (northern hemisphere) - Earth ..."**.